# Z3 Array which cannot be mutated

Tags: z3, smt

I have the following smtlib code:

```
(declare-fun res () (Array Int Int))
(declare-fun other () (Array Int Int))
(assert (not (=> (= res other) 
    (forall ((x Int))
                 (< (select res x) 4)))
    ))

(assert (= (select other 0) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

If I run it with z3 4.8.7 it is SAT and I get this model:

```
(model 
  (define-fun other () (Array Int Int)
    (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 1) 2 4))
  (define-fun res () (Array Int Int)
    (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 1) 2 4))
)
```

This means that both arrays are 'mutated' in order to fullfill the assertion (in the end it is making the forall-clause failing).
But I would like the other-array to be fixed. At the moment it behaves like a variable (say integer variable) but I want it be rather a constant (like a fixed number, i.e. 1, in case of integers). 
Refering to the statement (assert (= (select other 0) 1))
it simply should contain a 1 at position 0 and this must be fixed.
Is there a way to model this? 
If the other-array would behave like that then the above input should be UNSAT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want one of the arrays to be treated as having a variable interpretation, you need to use `(define-fun)` to define it rather than `(declare-fun)`. declare-fun declares an uninterpreted function, which means Z3 is free to assign any interpretation to it. If you look, the model you get back gives you some examples of how to use define-fun to define an array in smtlib.

Comment: This is true: if I use (define-fun other () (Array Int Int)
    ((as const (Array Int Int)) 1))  then it is UNSAT. But this array has a one at every position which can be indexed by an integer. I rather would want a 1 at position 0 and kind of undefiined every where else. How to model this?

Comment: Arrays are total functions. It's not possible for an array to have a value at some indices and not others. However, you can model something similar to what you describe using algebraic data types. You could create a type representing an optional integer with two constructors, present and empty, and define the Array as having empty everywhere except at certain indexes, where it has the present constructor with whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> it simply should contain a 1 at position 0 and this must be fixed.

But this is already true. The model:

```
 (define-fun other () (Array Int Int)
    (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 1) 2 4))
```

that you get might be tripping you up. The value there is a constant array with all entries set to `1`, except at index `2` which contains the value `4`.

So, the output already satisfies your constraints and has value `1` at index `0`, which seems to be what you are trying to model.